# Reformat columns mobile desktop Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay-theme

I'm making a website with Bootstrap 3. I have the following question: columns and then I have code that I show.

http://www.bootply.com/WASQQyGR8z

[image: desktop mode]

What I need is to transform this mobile mode "attached image" which is all on one line. How is possible??

[image: desktop mobile]

I attached the code that I have right now.

Thank you!

Greetings from Spain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

col-xs is for mobile size devices. Use col-xs-12 to make a column full width on a mobile device.

The documentation for bootstrap is very good. You should take a look. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

For the boxes inside you just use a nested .row and col-xs classes to suit. Again there is good documentation on this. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

See http://www.bootply.com/ktLMvltFVe

Comment: Hello @Legin76!

I understand what the al-xs but not placed as in the picture attached last. I can not do that in the text boxes in mobile mode move to the right of the image

Comment: I've updated my answer but you should read the documentation, as this is a basic of bootstrap.